# Use trait options or traitui.editor factory options?

Tags: python, traits, traitsui

When options for a Trait are available both in the traits definition and in the traitsui.DefaultEditor for this trait, what is the recommendation for which one to use and why?

E.g. the File trait has the option for a filter, which can also be defined in the traitsui.FileEditor()